# Using non-master Akka for sbt project

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, akka

In my sbt scala project, I want to use this https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/25317/files version of Akka library, to have a feature of MergeSortedN. How can I achieve it?

Comment: checkout the commit... build the code... publish to your local... and add it as a dependency to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To try it in your project you can:

1. Clone the repository which contains a fix `git clone https://github.com/tonicsoft/akka`
2. Enter to the project `cd akka`
3. Checkout the branch with a fix `git checkout fix-24369`
4. Run `sbt -Dakka.scaladoc.diagrams=false +publishLocal`
5. Correct dependency definitions for akka in your project to have the published version `2.6-SNAPSHOT`